# Custom payment screen for paypal android sdk

Tags: android-custom-view, paypal

i integrated paypal android sdk in our application and want to customize the payment screen i.e. action bar text, color and payment button text and color there seems to be no direct api to set color or sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the User Experience cannot be customized in the way that you would like.  I recommend taking a look at Braintree v.zero for a more customizable user experience.

Comment: does that make any difference if we use  Braintree for paypal. i mean do we need to sign different agreement with braintree although we already signed an agreement with paypal.

Comment: can we use braintree sdk provided we already have directly signed an agreement with paypal for payment gateway integration.

Comment: Sorry, as that's not a technical question, I cannot help.  I recommend you talk to the sales folks you worked with when signing the agreement.